# Add Custom Text Value to BarChart AChartEngine

Tags: android, graph, bar-chart, achartengine

I want to have a different textvalue on top of my barchart. The value is different because i want a logarithmic kind of scaling. How can I achieve this?
Many thanks.

I searched for other questions but all those questions are older than a year and I can't find any up to date information:(

New exception after adding series.addAnnotation(...);

**code**

```
public GraphicalView getView(Context context, List<Double> height, List<String> text, List<String> time) {

    XYSeries series = new XYSeries(null);
    for(int i = 0; i < height.size(); i++) {
        series.add(i, height.get(i));
        series.addAnnotation(text.get(i), (double) i, height.get(i));
    }
    XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = new XYMultipleSeriesDataset();
    dataset.addSeries(series);

    XYSeriesRenderer renderer = new XYSeriesRenderer();     
    //renderer.setDisplayChartValues(true);
    renderer.setColor(Color.parseColor("#3399cc"));

    XYMultipleSeriesRenderer mRenderer = new XYMultipleSeriesRenderer();
    mRenderer.addSeriesRenderer(renderer);

    ...
```

**Exception**

```
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424): java.lang.NullPointerException
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at org.achartengine.chart.XYChart.draw(XYChart.java:305)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at org.achartengine.GraphicalView.onDraw(GraphicalView.java:168)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13776)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12727)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13500)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3171)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3041)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12725)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13500)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3171)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3041)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12725)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13500)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3171)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3041)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13779)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.widget.ScrollView.draw(ScrollView.java:1821)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12727)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13500)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3171)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3041)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13779)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12727)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13500)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3171)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3041)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13779)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12727)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13500)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3171)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3041)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12725)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13500)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.drawChild(ViewGroup.java:3171)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchDraw(ViewGroup.java:3041)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.draw(View.java:13779)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.widget.FrameLayout.draw(FrameLayout.java:467)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.draw(PhoneWindow.java:2420)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12727)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.View.getDisplayList(View.java:12771)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.HardwareRenderer$GlRenderer.draw(HardwareRenderer.java:1144)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.draw(ViewRootImpl.java:2278)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performDraw(ViewRootImpl.java:2150)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1961)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1115)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:4526)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:725)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:555)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:525)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:711)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
    06-11 13:49:49.256: E/AndroidRuntime(18424):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The option you have is related to annotations. Add one for each bar, like this:

```
series.addAnnotation("text", x, y);
```

Comment: I changed my CategorySeries to XYSeries to try to make the annotations working, however when i launch my app. Logcat returns a NullPointerException in XYChart.draw when i add any notations, how can i solve this?

Comment: Please post the exception and the code. I cannot guess otherwise.

Comment: Make sure your height and text lists don't contain null values.

Comment: can you specify the x and y values,